# Свое окно в TrayClock и его подсказки

Tags: delphi

D10.1Starter, W10EntLtsb.
"Очередные свои часы в трее".

Есть форма, на ней панель(`P`). На форме кнопки "Скрыть", "Показать", соответственно hide\show в действиях. При клике на панели = `form.show`;
+еще есть таймер (1сек), кот.содержит `P.hint=datetimetostr(now);` У `P.showhint:=true;` (+паренты showhint false). В переменных формы еще есть `re:TRect; h:HWND;`
На окно с часами в трее сажусь так:

```
procedure MyHook;
    ....
    try
        h:=FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd',nil);
        h:=FindWindowEx(h,0,'TrayNotifyWnd',nil);
        h:=FindWindowEx(h,0,'TrayClockWClass', nil);

        if h=0 then begin 
            GuErr('Часы в трее выключены в настройках');
            halt(13);
        end;

        GetWindowRect(h,re);
        p.Top := 0;
        p.Left := 0;
        p.Height := re.Height;
        p.Width := re.Width;

        p.Visible := true;
        Winapi.Windows.SetParent(p.Handle,h);
    except on e:exception do 
        GuErr('MyClock error: '+e.Message);
    end;
    ...
end;
```

При старте форма скрывается, остается только панель `P` на часах. Прозрачная, все Ок. При клике на ней соответственно вылезет основное окно.
Когда основное окно активно, и мышку наводим на виндовые часы - видно хинт от таймера (текущее время-прим.не хинт часов виндов). Если форму скрыть, то хинт больше не показывается (если активировать основное окно, то снова видно).

**Вопрос**

*Почему? Уже извращался как только мог. Что не так и что сделать, чтобы он показывался когда основное окно скрыто?*

Пока добавил такой костыль (в переменных формы добавил `hw:thintwindow=nil;`):

На панели

```
procedure TForm1.pMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
const a = 50;
var re1: trect;
begin
    if hw = nil then begin
        re1 := re;
        re1.Top := re.Top - a;
        re1.Left := re.Left - a;
        re1.Height := re.Height + a;
        re1.Width := re.Width + a;

        hw := thintwindow.Create(p);
        hw.Hint := p.Hint;
        //hw.Left:=0;hw.top:=0;hw.Width:=50;hw.Height:=200;
        hw.ActivateHint(re1, hw.Hint);
    end;
end;
```

и

```
procedure TForm1.pMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if hw<>nil then begin 
        hw.Free;
        hw:=nil;
    end;
end;
```

Я пытался заменить панель окном отдельным, но сложновато для меня или панель по разному присвоить а-ля `as tcontrol(h)` при поиске окошка виндового трея но все сводится к ошибке *"has no parent window"* при создании. помогите плз.

Задача почти решена - своя форма при клике на часах вин. +сами виндовые часы видно (оставил затею туда свое запихать (только как значок если отдельный), отдельный вопрос), но вот вопрос с отображением подсказки в виде другого формата времени (не предлагать менять в виндах, там еще другие сведения будут)  не могу осилить.

Comment: вы думаете, что если писать код в одну строку, без пробелов и отступов, программа меньше места занимать будет, работать быстрее. или это круче и показывает ваше умение читать код также хорошо как и компилятор?

Comment: так вставляет сюда. потом меньше места занимает и пробелов надо меньше кликать чтобы как код показывало. да и код небольшой. +спасибо за правки.